# How to join with fill null by previous value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables that I want to join with filling null values by previous (closest by date).

```
CREATE TABLE a
( a_value int,
  a_date DATE,
  a_id int
);

CREATE TABLE b
( b_id int,
  b_date DATE,
  b_value float
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, '20130603', 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, '20130704', 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (3, '20130805', 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, '20130906', 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (2, '20131007', 1);

INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, '20130603', 3.00);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, '20130706', 4.00);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, '20130906', 5.00);
```

I need to join like this, but I get null values in some a_dates.

```
SELECT a.a_value,
a.a_date,
a.a_id,
b.b_value,
b.b_date
FROM b
RIGHT JOIN a on a.a_id = b.b_id
AND b.b_date <= a.a_date
AND b.b_date >= timestampadd(day, -25, a.a_date)
ORDER BY a.a_date;
```

Result:

| a_value | a_date | a_id | b_value | b_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-06-03 | 1 | 3 | 2013-06-03 |
| 1 | 2013-07-04 | 1 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2013-08-05 | 1 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2013-09-06 | 1 | 5 | 2013-09-06 |
| 2 | 2013-10-07 | 1 | (null) | (null) |

But I would like to get with fill missing values by closest by date

| a_value | a_date | a_id | b_value | b_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-06-03 | 1 | 3 | 2013-06-03 |
| 1 | 2013-07-04 | 1 | **3** | **2013-06-03** |
| 3 | 2013-08-05 | 1 | **4** | **2013-07-06** |
| 1 | 2013-09-06 | 1 | 5 | 2013-09-06 |
| 2 | 2013-10-07 | 1 | **5** | **2013-09-06** |

I tried to use coalesce:

```
and coalesce(b.b_date, 
             (select b_date 
              from b as b1 
              where b1.b_date <a.a_date and b1.b_value is not null
              order by b1.b_date desc
             LIMIT 1)) <= a.a_date;
```

But get duplicates rows :(

How should I do it?

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to get than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: What database are you using? A lateral join can be optimal if available.

Comment: @jarlh I agree wholeheartedly. Most people don't understand right joins correctly, specially when they follow more than two tables.

Comment: @The Impaler MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh I tried to use "main table left join optional data", where the main table is a and left joined is b, but the result is the same: I can't get what I want =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  a_value 
       ,a_date  
       ,a_id    
       ,b_id    
       ,b_date  
       ,b_value
from
(
select  *
       ,rank() over(partition by a_id, a_date, a_value order by datediff(a_date, b_date)) as rnk
from    a full join b
where   b_date <= a_date
) ab
where   rnk = 1
```

| a_value | a_date | a_id | b_id | b_date | b_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-06-03 | 1 | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 3 |
| 1 | 2013-07-04 | 1 | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 3 |
| 3 | 2013-08-05 | 1 | 1 | 2013-07-06 | 4 |
| 1 | 2013-09-06 | 1 | 1 | 2013-09-06 | 5 |
| 2 | 2013-10-07 | 1 | 1 | 2013-09-06 | 5 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2PkxTks1)